# Converting Word Table to iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, phone.app

I have a my contact list on my PC, formatted as a table in Word (.doc). Is there a convenient way to transfer this info into my iPhone 7+ contact list other than manual data entry?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to import the contacts stored in the Word table into the macOS Contacts Application. These are the steps to get your Word table over to Contacts:

1. Copy the whole word table into the clipboard (cmd-C)
2. Paste what you’ve copied into a new excel spreadsheet (cmd-V)
3. Save the Excel sheet into a CSV file (comma-separated values
4. Open the macOS Contacts application and select File > Import (cmd-O)
5. A dialog appears in which you can specify how the import file components will be assigned to the Contacts fields. Click Ok when you’re done to start the import process.

Once the contacts live inside the Contacts app you can easily synchronise them onto the iPhone using iCloud or iTunes.

Hope this helps.